# New Dell laptop crashing with unusual screen output

Tags: laptop, freeze

Working at a small company, we just refreshed our aging HP laptops with [Dell Latitude 5491 (14 inch) laptops](https://www.dell.com/en-au/work/shop/business-laptops-ultrabooks-and-tablets/new-latitude-5491/spd/latitude-14-5491-laptop), equipped with 1Tb SSDs and 32GB RAM, running Windows 10.

We're using them with dual HD monitors via [Dell TB16 Thunderbolt](https://www.dell.com/en-au/work/shop/dell-thunderbolt-dock-tb16-240w/apd/452-bcnj/pc-accessories) docks.

For the most part, they have been fine although Dell seem to be frequently releasing firmware updates, for the laptops as well as the docks.

However, on one of the machine/dock combos we're seeing daily crashes, with the following symptoms

- Keyboard backlight is lit up
- Keys are all unresponsive (including light on caps lock key)
- Cooling fan is running
- To power the machine off, you have to press & hold the power button for 5+ seconds
- Dual screens both show a series of vertical lines, as per photos below

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

We've replaced the laptop, **and** the dock and somehow for this one user we're still seeing the same issue.

On closer inspection, I noticed that a pretty beat up micro-USB Huwawei cable was plugged into the dock.

[image: USB cable]

Could this be causing the issues, and/or can anyone suggest what else might be?

Comment: You’ve already replaced two components. Unfortunately a lot of hardware troubleshooting nowadays is simply swap and test. Just keep unplugging things and swapping things until you find the culprit. That USB cable looks horrible.